# Probability of Type II Error for F Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, anova, variance, sampling

I have the following problem, and am stuck at a certain point in the calculations:

A butter-packing machine in a dairy packs butter in 250g packages though the actual weights packed vary. It is proposed to replace the machine with a new model which, it is claimed, has smaller variability in package weights. Suppose the variance of the new machine is actually one-third that of the old, i.e.  $\sigma_{new}^2 = \frac{1}{3}\sigma_{old}^2$.  On the basis of $13$ trials of the old machine and $12$ trials of the new machine a $5\%$ level test is to be made of $H_0:\sigma_{new}^2 = \sigma_{old}^2$ against $H_1:\sigma_{new}^2 < \sigma_{old}^2$ What is the probability that a type II error will be made.

I was able to check if we accept or reject $H_0$ at a $5\%$ level. Namely:

$$f=\frac{\sigma_{old}^2}{\sigma_{new}^2} = 3 >F_{0.05}^{(12,11)} = 2.7875$$

Therefore, we reject $H_0$. For calculating the type II error, I am not even sure that I am phrasing it correctly:

$$P\left(\text{accept } H_0|\sigma_{new}^2 = \frac{1}{3}\sigma_{old}^2\right)$$

I do not know where to take it from here.

Comment: You need to start by finding the critical value of the test. If the test statistic is $F = S_o^2/S_n^2,$ presumably you will reject $H_0$ at the 5% level if $P(F > c|H_0) = P(F > c|\sigma_o^2=\sigma_n^2) = 0.05.$ Then the power against alternative that $\sigma_0^2=3\sigma_n^2$ is computed using that assumption. That is $P(F > c|\sigma_0^2=3\sigma_n^2) = ??$

Comment: This seems to be a textbook problem. Than you for showing your thoughts so far. Please consider adding the `Self-study` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a textbook problem. So I will leave it to you to give
a formal analytic solution. Here is a simulation in R to
illustrate my Comment in the case $\sigma_o^2 = 3$ and $\sigma_n^2 = 1.$
It seems that the power you seek is $P(\mathrm{Reject\,}H_0\,|\,\sigma_o^2 = 3\sigma_n^2) \approx 0.55.$

```
set.seed(2020) 
f.0 = replicate( 10^6, var(rnorm(13, 250, sqrt(3)))/var(rnorm(12, 250, sqrt(3))) )
c = quantile(f.0, .95); c
     95% 
2.781374             $ aprx 2.7876
qf(.95, 12, 11)
[1] 2.787569

set.seed(904) 
f.a = replicate( 10^6, var(rnorm(13, 250, sqrt(3)))/var(rnorm(12, 250, 1)) )
mean(f.a > c)
[1] 0.553615         # aprx power

par(mfrow=c(2,1))
 hist(f.0, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main="Null")
  abline(v=c, col="red")
  curve(df(x,12,11), add=T)
 hist(f.a, prob=T, br=100, col="skyblue2", main="Alternative")
  abline(v=c, col="red")
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]